# gradle ASCII: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Friday gradle works fine, today I got this gradle error:

```
* Where:
Build file '...\git\project\app\build.gradle' line: 1
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII

CONFIGURE FAILED in 4s
ASCII
```

error with `gradle --debug`:

```
...
10:29:50.018 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
10:29:50.018 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
10:29:50.018 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
10:29:50.018 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Where:
10:29:50.019 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Build file '...\git\project\project\build.gradle' line: 1
10:29:50.019 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
10:29:50.019 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
10:29:50.019 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
10:29:50.019 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > ASCII
10:29:50.019 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
10:29:50.019 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
10:29:50.019 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
10:29:50.019 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
10:29:50.019 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
10:29:50.019 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
10:29:50.019 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 1s
10:29:50.019 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1 completed (0 worker(s) in use)
10:29:50.019 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker: released lock on root.1
10:29:50.020 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Run build'
10:29:50.020 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Run build' completed
10:29:50.022 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for cache directory md-supplier (C:\Users\Utente\.gradle\caches\4.10\md-supplier)
10:29:50.023 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on cache directory md-supplier (C:\Users\Utente\.gradle\caches\4.10\md-supplier).
10:29:50.025 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for cache directory md-rule (C:\Users\Utente\.gradle\caches\4.10\md-rule)
10:29:50.025 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on cache directory md-rule (C:\Users\Utente\.gradle\caches\4.10\md-rule).
10:29:50.026 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
10:29:50.027 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
10:29:50.027 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.ResolutionResultsStoreFactory] Deleted 2 resolution results binary files in 0.001 secs
10:29:50.027 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.deployment.internal.DefaultDeploymentRegistry] Stopping 0 deployment handles
10:29:50.028 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.deployment.internal.DefaultDeploymentRegistry] Stopped deployment handles
10:29:50.028 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for file hash cache (...\git\project\.gradle\4.10\fileHashes)
10:29:50.028 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on file hash cache (...\git\project\.gradle\4.10\fileHashes).
...
```

**my app build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
  …
}
```

my build.gradle version: 3.1.1

my gradle distribution version: 4.10

How Can I solve this issue? What is the problem?

Comment: please try to execute your build using `gradle --info` first, then `gradle --debug` to get more info.

Comment: I executed the build using `gradle --info` and I got the same error. Whereas the error I got using `gradle --debug` I edit my question

Comment: Post your `app\build.gradle` please

Comment: same problem here!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the Artifactory lib version. I use this lib `org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle` and with the last version `4.9.1`, I got the problem, whereas with the `4.9.0`, all works fine.

Comment: In which file should I make this change?

Comment: in the `build.gradle` project file

Answer (score 30):

I edited the android (project level) build.gradle file and changed

com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1

to

com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1

Comment: also then you may have to update gradle-wrapper.properties.

in android studio - press ctrl-shift n to bring up the file search bar, type "gradle-wrapper.properties" and then change the distributionUrl to the following:

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

Answer (score 10):

**Just Follow these Steps in Android Studio**

Click on the file in the menu bar

click on Project Structure

change Android Gradle plugin version to 3.5.1

sync again

Comment: Update Gradle plugin to latest version fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

The way it worked for me is to change the gradle version to be compatible with the kotlin version.

In `android/gradle/gradle-warpper.properties`

change `gradle-5.6.2-all.zip` to `gradle-6.1.1-all.zip`

I hope this solution works for you too

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file `android/build.gradle` file and change

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1
```

**to**

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4
```

This solved my problem.
All the best for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below to your **TOP LEVEL** `build.gradle`

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed dependency at gradle.build - Project as follows:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited the android (project level) build.gradle file and changed

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1
```

to

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most of these answers suggest upgrading Gradle, which is **only** technically correct.

> **Also undesired**, because we noticed that Gradle-plugin versions later than 3.1.3 (i.e. `gradle-4.4-all.zip`),
> require about 2 GB additional RAM (at least at time of writting, 2022).

Hence we used Git-history to find **root cause** (which for us at least) was using the latest Kotlin version ("1.5.30").

In other words, instead of upgrading Gradle, we did simply undo changing Kotlin version, like:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3') {
            exclude module: 'proguard-gradle'
        }
        classpath('net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.0') { force = true }

        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

> **Note** that above uses old Gradle-plugin
> but overrides ProGuard with latest-version (at time of writting).
>
> Such thing may not even be possible with new Gradle versions, because they use R8.