# Gradle failure A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

I am trying to build the gradle for my app but the build fails

I've looked around some other questions regarding to this issue and I couldn't solve it.
Also, I have tried changing the gradle build tool version, adding different lib and some more stuff which didn't mange to solve the problem.

[pubspec.yaml](https://pastebin.com/nuWdtwCg)

Project level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App level build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.2.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

After using gradle --stacktrace i get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\Development\Projects\MyProjects\app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:92)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:204)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:209)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:61)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:58)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:41)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:64)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:110)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:667)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluationDependsOn(DefaultProject.java:747)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluationDependsOn(DefaultProject.java:739)
        at org.gradle.api.Project$evaluationDependsOn.call(Unknown Source)
        at build_4s2wu7zh7cf5gkrqlj5jziodv$_run_closure3.doCall(D:\Development\Projects\MyProjects\app\android\build.gradle:25)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:160)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator$3.run(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:100)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.runProjectConfigureClosure(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:96)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.access$400(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator$1.doRunProjectConfigure(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:81)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator$BlockConfigureBuildOperation.run(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:144)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.runBlockConfigureClosure(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:78)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.subprojects(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.subprojects(DefaultProject.java:1119)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:479)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:191)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:30)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BasicScript.java:134)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:160)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.invokeMethod(BasicScript.java:83)
        at build_4s2wu7zh7cf5gkrqlj5jziodv.run(D:\Development\Projects\MyProjects\app\android\build.gradle:24)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:90)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:204)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:209)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:61)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:58)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:41)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:64)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:110)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:667)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:136)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:60)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:261)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:173)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:132)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:115)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ASCII
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.checkPathForErrors(BasePlugin.java:1006)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.apply(BasePlugin.java:261)
        at com.android.build.gradle.AbstractAppPlugin.apply(AbstractAppPlugin.java:122)
        at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.apply(AppPlugin.java:43)
        at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.apply(AppPlugin.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginTarget.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginTarget.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:164)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.access$200(DefaultPluginManager.java:47)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager$AddPluginBuildOperation.run(DefaultPluginManager.java:252)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:144)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:125)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:120)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:86)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:143)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at build_38z6bfg6sklosvddu68v2kav9.run(D:\Development\Projects\MyProjects\app\android\app\build.gradle:24)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:90)
        ... 146 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

After running gradle --info

```
Initialized native services in: C:\Users\Alon\.gradle\native
Found daemon DaemonInfo{pid=9132, address=[1188a464-723f-4e03-8889-a8aac56f1b3d port:50296, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1564299092334, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=1fefa30a-a771-48fb-bc97-9b85efee7704,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Alon\.gradle\daemon,pid=9132,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} however its context does not match the desired criteria.
At least one daemon option is different.
Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Alon\.gradle\daemon,pid=4300,idleTimeout=null,daemonOpts=-Xmx1536M,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=1fefa30a-a771-48fb-bc97-9b85efee7704,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Alon\.gradle\daemon,pid=9132,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]

  Looking for a different daemon...
The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 5312). The daemon log file: C:\Users\Alon\.gradle\daemon\4.6\daemon-5312.out.log
Starting 12th build in daemon [uptime: 39 mins 49.473 secs, performance: 100%, no major garbage collections]
Using 4 worker leases.
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file 'D:\Development\Projects\MyProjects\app\android\settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'D:\Development\Projects\MyProjects\app\android\build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'android', project ':app', project ':cloud_firestore', project ':firebase_core']
Evaluating root project 'android' using build file 'D:\Development\Projects\MyProjects\app\android\build.gradle'.
Evaluating project ':app' using build file 'D:\Development\Projects\MyProjects\app\android\app\build.gradle'.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\Development\Projects\MyProjects\app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
VCS Checkout Cache (D:\Development\Projects\MyProjects\app\android\.gradle\vcsWorkingDirs) has not been cleaned up in 0 days
```

Do you know how this problem can be solved?

Comment: Is it happening in a new app created with `flutter create`?

Comment: @10101010 No, the build is successful when creating a new flutter app

Comment: Could you please add the contents of your `pubspec.yaml`? It might be one of the packages causing this issue.

Comment: @10101010 added

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gradle ASCII: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627009/gradle-ascii-a-problem-occurred-evaluating-project-app)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**Update 2022-04-26**:

It is possible that the root cause is using a Kotlin version which is not compatible with older versions of Gradle. A possible fix is downgrading the version of Kotlin below 1.2.71, or more sensibly, upgrading Gradle.

**Update 2019-12-13:**

As of Flutter 1.12 (stable) released on Dec 11 **2019**, Flutter boilerplate [now includes](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/40181) gradle distribution 5.6.2 and plugin version 3.5.0 which will hopefully make this a historical SO question. Plugin version 3.5.3 is current, but even version 3.5.0 should fix the issue as initially reported.

**Original answer**:

This appears to be caused by the Flutter boilerplate specifying an old version of the gradle plugin. I'm still unclear if Flutter package updates in pubspec.yaml/lock are triggering the issue, I rolled back a way but it was still present here.

For some reason this affects my Windows 10 system, but not my Mac development environment. Both are up-to-date (Flutter 1.7.8+hotfix.4) and on the same versions of everything as far as I'm aware. On account of this Windows path separators are used in the notes below.

In `android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` the Flutter boilerplate specifies a gradle distribution of 4.10.2, which supports a plugin version of up to 3.3.2. However, `android\build.gradle` only depends on plugin version 3.2.1 (`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'`). It's unclear why the Flutter boilerplate isn't more internally consistent.

To resolve, change `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1` => `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2`, run `flutter clean` and try the build again.

According to the [gradle release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#3-4-0), the current (July 2019) version of the plugin and gradle are 3.4.2 and 5.1.1 respectively. I don't know if Flutter officially supports this version, although it seems to work on my project here and a clean build is markedly faster. The release notes cover some of the changes from 3.2.x => 3.3.x => 3.4.x.

To upgrade to the current version, edit `android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` to source gradle 5.1.1, and then you're able to upgrade the gradle plugin to 3.4.2.

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
```

Note that once gradle 5.1.1 is being used, you can still set the plugin version back to 3.2.1 to reproduce the issue.

I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37523) with the Flutter team to try and understand this better and will update this answer if they come back with anything concrete.

Comment: Man thank you that was it! 3.1.1 didn't work for me, had to change just one number xD

Comment: Hi @JulianWagner,can you please mention what is the version classpath you have given for proper working ?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue changing google services classpath from 4.3.0 to 4.2.0 made that fixed.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

change this into

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Answer (score 6):

I managed to solve the problem by creating a new project with `flutter create` and copying the lib folder over to the new project and also the changes needed for the gradle (also changing the google-services classpath version to 4.2.0) and pubspec.

Answer (score 3):

I changed my project/build.gradle file like following:

```
// ... 
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    // ... 
}
```

In here, my project uses kotlin-gradle-plugin which has a dependency on `"$kotlin_version"`. And Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.0 and higher. So, I changed the value of kotlin_version on the same "**build.gradle**" file.

Just change

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
```

to

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'
```

And, also you need to go to **"android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties"** file and change it to this:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-all.zip
```

Now, run "**flutter clean**" and then "**flutter run**" command. It works perfectly !

Answer (score 2):

Tried changing 'com.google.gms:google-services: to various versions.

That did not work.

I solved it like this:

1. Create a new flutter project.
2. Copy all the source files and folders.

(May need to change copied folders to 'sources'
File>Project Structure>
Project Settings>project name>Sources
select the folder then click 'Source' above the file name)

3. Copy pubspec.yaml file over and run Pub git
4. Close the project
5. Open the project again

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this problem many times now, this is a common problem when you're working projects not made on your system but are rather imported from an external source.

I had tried the answers above but everything was ineffective, the only thing that solved this problem for me was making these two changes in the **app level build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties() //write the keyword new if not already  there
```

and inside the if block for checking the flutter root, change the method **GradleException** to **FileNotFoundException**

Change

```
 if (flutterRoot == null) {
   throw GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
 }
```

to

```
if (flutterRoot == null) {
   throw FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
```

Doing the above steps may result in an error, which can be fixed by selecting the latest Android API level as your project SDK

[image: Setting up latest Android API level as project SDK]

If the above steps do not work, try changing your gradle and gradle plugin versions as follows

in your **Android level build.gradle file**, add the following commented line

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0' //add this line
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
}
```

Then in **gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file**, add the distribution URL as:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

Finally run the commands **flutter clean** and then **flutter run**, the project should run fine

Comment: "this is a common problem when you're working projects not made on your system but are rather imported from an external source" appears to be true. I tried to open a project created in Cordova into Android Studio and I ended with a build error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I think if you use the versions of these dependencies, it should work.

```
PATH: <project-folder>/android/build.gradle

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having troubles, make sure that you have Google Play services enabled in the SDK Tools in Android Studio.

I still had the error after I changed my google-services from `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'` to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'`.

After I enabled Google Play services, the error was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I think if you use the versions of these dependencies, it should work.

- /android/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NB! Windows 10

I removed Users/username/.gradle directory
Upgraded gradle from 6.5.1 to 7.4.2
Before gradle i upgraded jdk
removed old project/android folder
run cmd in admin mode
run expo run:android twice
and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this issue on my system.This is a problem that has to do with your kotlin version. Always update kotlin to the latest version. You can get the latest version of kotlin [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#targeting-multiple-platforms). Currently the latest kotlin version is '1.7.20'

ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20' in build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

It was an obfuscation problem. I had to change `minifyEnabled` and `runProguard` to true and the problem was solved.