# Build failed with an exception in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to connect my app with firebase while i run my app it shows an error -
* Where:
Build file 'D:\AndroidStudio\login\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

Here my app level build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.mdhv.login"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here my project level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

After running my app it shows below error -

- Error running Gradle:
  ProcessException: Process "D:\AndroidStudio\login\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\AndroidStudio\login\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > ASCII
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
  Command: D:\AndroidStudio\login\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

After running 'flutter run -v' it shows -

```
   Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      _readGradleProject (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:158:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _gradleProject (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:111:34)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      getGradleAppOut (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:105:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      AndroidApk.fromAndroidProject (package:flutter_tools/src/application_package.dart:160:23)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      ApplicationPackageFactory.getPackageForPlatform (package:flutter_tools/src/application_package.dart:47:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      FlutterDevice.runHot (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:352:56)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      HotRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_hot.dart:251:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:469:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:478:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:383:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#13     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#14     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#15     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#16     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#17     FlutterCommand.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:375:20)
#18     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:396:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#20     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#21     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#22     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#23     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#24     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#25     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#26     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:356:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#27     CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:25)
#28     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)
#29     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:14)
#30     FlutterCommandRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:242:18)
#31     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
#32     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#33     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#34     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#35     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1500:12)
#36     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:60:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#37     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#38     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#39     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#40     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#41     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#42     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#43     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:56:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#44     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:51:10)
#45     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:62:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#46     main (file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8:3)
#47     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
#48     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
```

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?

Comment: Build file 'D:\AndroidStudio\login\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

Comment: Could you please add the result when you try 'flutter run -v' and your 'flutter doctor -v' in this post (run in terminal)? This gives us (and you) a better insight in your error.

Comment: 'flutter doctor -v' shows having no issue

Comment: Here u go check out 'flutter run -v'

Comment: You can check my solution. I've posted it here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59010959/12421651

Answer (score 3):

I also had this issue, changing

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

To

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Fixed it for me.

Comment: Downgrade worked for me, but seems root issue was 'com.android.tools.build:gradle' version incompatibility (I bump it to 3.4.2 and was able to build with google-services 4.3.2)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and solved it by:

- Press `Win + R` and type resmon.exe and press enter.
- Go to CPU tab
- Type "build" in Associated Handles Search Bar below.
- Right click on "java.exe" and End Process.
- Go to your IDE and run `flutter clean`.
- Get all the dependencies again by running `pub get`.

This worked for me.