# gradle task assemblerelease failed with exit code 1 - flutter run --release

Tags: flutter, gradle

my flutter application working normally in debug mode but when I tried to run it as a release mode an error of `gradle task assemblerelease failed with exit code 1` appears I did

- flutter clean
  and then `flutter run --release` 
  the same problem
  i deleted the .gradle files same issue still appears
  i changed class path from
  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'`
  to
  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'`
  not workes
  i dont know what to do
  the `flutter run --release -v` log is

```
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      _buildGradleProjectV2 (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:751:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      buildGradleProject (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:494:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/apk.dart:34:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      AndroidDevice.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:486:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterDevice.runCold (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:439:46)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      ColdRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_cold.dart:65:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:472:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:490:18)
#9      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
#10     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#11     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#12     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
#13     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
#14     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
#15     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
#16     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:30:15)
#17     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:288:13)
#18     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
#19     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
#20     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#21     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#22     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
#23     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
#24     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
#25     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
#26     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:30:15)
#27     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:288:13)
#28     AndroidDevice.isLocalEmulator (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart)
#29     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
#30     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#31     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#32     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
#33     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
#34     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
#35     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
#36     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:552:7)
#37     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#38     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#39     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#40     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
#41     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#42     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#43     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:116:13)
#44     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:173:5)
```

`flutter doctor` -v log is

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Mac OS X 10.15.1 19B88, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.6 at /Users/tabarekaljaaf/flutter
    • Framework revision 68587a0916 (12 months ago), 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/tabarekaljaaf/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 29.0.1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3.1, Build version 11C504
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 47.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.48.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.14.1

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM G965F • 24192e34f80c7ece • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

• No issues found!
```

how to solve it?
P.S. I have

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.enableR8=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in my gradle.properties
also, i don't want to update my flutter version

Comment: there must be some error in your gradle files . Check both app level and project level gradle files . Also check AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: What i have to check in these files , they are all existing

Comment: check whether android studio is showing some warning /error in these files . If that is the case try to resolve them. After resolving all the errors , build your project in release mode

Comment: this might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57322750/build-failed-with-an-exception-in-flutter

Comment: i got this warning when i make a build in android studio  .. anything could help me                          
build.gradle: API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.