# A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

I cloned a working project from git , and starting to run it but this error shown up. However on another laptop it works fine showing no errors. that I thought the problem is my laptop, but trying to run a different projects and they worked successfully

```
ProcessException: Process "E:\cantina-customer\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'E:\cantina-customer\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get
more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
  Command: E:\cantina-customer\android\gradlew.bat app:properties


Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

and here my build.gradle/appLevel

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28


    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "app.cantina.customer"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have tried to run a different application and it worked fine without any errors , any idea on How can I solve this in this project specifically?

Comment: what is that 'z' after compileSdkVersion 28 ? is a copy paste mistake ?

Comment: yes it is a copy paste mistake sorry, edited

Comment: Make sure everything is up-to-date, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57238933/gradle-failure-a-problem-occurred-evaluating-project-app