# I try running my first Flutter app on a Pixel 5 Emulator but I keep getting this error message in Visual Studio Code

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'C:\Users\Deepan Dey\Documents\Flutter\flutter\examples\hello_world\android\settings.gradle' line: 16

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
> assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
         |                   |
         |                   false
         C:\Users\Deepan Dey\Documents\Flutter\flutter\examples\hello_world\android\local.properties
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.


BUILD FAILED in 28s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I am a complete noob in Flutter. This app is running just fine on Chrome but just won't run on an Android Emulator.

Comment: Do you get error while  running `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: No I don't get any error while running flutter `doctor -v`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle failure A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57238933/gradle-failure-a-problem-occurred-evaluating-project-app)

Comment: Do you have android studio installed ? Have you set your android sdk path in your $PATH ?

Comment: Yes I do have android studio installed and I have it added in my path