# Flutter run returns: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'." ">ASCII"

Tags: firebase, gradle, flutter, dart

I'm trying to follow the "Add firebase to flutter" tutorial (https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup) . I've done this with many prior version.

Now on Flutter 1.9 I'm getting "A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'." ">ASCII". Is this a known issue?

Flutter doctor:

```
PS C:\DEV\auth> flutter doctor -v

[√] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 31.3.1
    • Dart plugin version 181.5656
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.39.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.5.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'  // Google Services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.auth"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gradle ASCII: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627009/gradle-ascii-a-problem-occurred-evaluating-project-app)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried everything.  All I could do is down grade to:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
}
```

---

Gradle version

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

Then everything went smoothly again.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using higher version of google-services, for me the version worked

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

sadly this can be a variety of things it seems.

Try version bumping as the guys write above, however for me it was actually a need to add

minifyEnabled true, specifically in app/build.gradle add

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            **minifyEnabled true**
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```