# A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > ASCII

Tags: android, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to link a plain Flutter project with Firebase database.
I am using Firebase database version 2.0.0, since version 3.0.5 didn't compile....

Every thing looks smooth until I add the dependencies:

build.gradle(project):

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
}
```

build.gradle(app):

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and my pubspec.yaml has the following dependencies:

```
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
firebase_database: ^2.0.0
```

and the Error I am getting is:

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\hassa\Desktop\testing\new1\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\hassa\Desktop\testing\new1\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run 
with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
  Command: C:\Users\hassa\Desktop\testing\new1\android\gradlew.bat app:properties


Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

my build.gradle(app):

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.new1"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

update:
upon updating my  com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 to com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1  gradle wrapper into 5.1.0 i am getting this error now

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\hassa\Desktop\testing\new1\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

> Configure project :app
WARNING: API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'. 
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getJavaCompile(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to 
display more information.
WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'. 
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getMergeAssets(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to 
display more information.
WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with
'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variantOutput.getProcessResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the      
command line to display more information.
  Command: C:\Users\hassa\Desktop\testing\new1\android\gradlew.bat app:properties


Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

any help about the new error?

Comment: What is the line 24 of the `C:\Users\hassa\Desktop\testing\new1\android\app\build.gradle` file?

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Comment: Can you share the complete file?

Comment: hi....shared above (edited) thanks alot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gradle ASCII: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627009/gradle-ascii-a-problem-occurred-evaluating-project-app)

Answer (score 0):

update classpath to new version

From

`com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1`

to

`com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1`

Also need to update gradle-wrapper to,

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip`

Comment: hello Abhay...by gradle-wrapper you mean this line:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip to which version should i update to?