# A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > ASCII on intellij IDE for android app development uisng kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I have started working on the android project with kotlin and firebase. I have created an account on firebase and register the project and follow the given step it has been giving me the following error.
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> ASCII

```
apply plugin:'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.highness"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
}
```

This is my build.gradle(app) file where the error is indicated.
Please suggest me something

Comment: Where did u define $kotlin_version? Please share your log details.

Comment: Thank you for your interest Vijay but the problem is got solved

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gradle ASCII: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627009/gradle-ascii-a-problem-occurred-evaluating-project-app)

Answer (score 1):

0
Problem is get solve when I changed dependencies as follow

Project-level build.gradle:

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'`
App-level build.gradle:

`implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4"`